# Set size of "screenshot"

Tags: html2canvas

I try to use your library to make screenshot but I don't succeed to choose the size.

```
html2canvas(document.body, {width:200, height:200}).then(function(canvas) {
     document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

Can I do it ?

Comment: @MrLister: Whoever wrote this library, I would have thought.

Comment: @MrLister: That seems to be a fairly obvious "yes"!. Does it make a difference to the question's answerability?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It may make a difference in how the OP sees us and communicates with us. It's not just about answering, but also about seeing the answer being accepted as correct